# codeigniter using AS when selecting a database

Tags: codeigniter

I cant find any info on the user guide for doing JOIN AS, here is what i'm trying to do:

```
SELECT 
c.id
,c.name AS companyName
,con.id AS conID
,l.id AS lid

FROM
     company AS c
LEFT JOIN
     contacts AS con ON
     c.primary_contact = con.id
LEFT JOIN
     locations AS l ON
    c.id = l.cid
```

anyone have a quick solution, or point me to the section in the guide that I cant seem to find with the AS statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this

```
SELECT 
    c.id
   ,c.name AS companyName
   ,con.id AS conID
   ,l.id AS lid

FROM
   company c
LEFT JOIN
   contacts con ON
   c.primary_contact = con.id
LEFT JOIN
   locations l ON
   c.id = l.cid
```

You need not mention join table names also with AS,If you give the name after the table name it will automatically aliases your table that you are joining.

Try in Ci like

```
$this->db->select('c.id
                  ,c.name AS companyName
                  ,con.id AS conID
                  ,l.id AS lid'); 
$this->db->from('company c');        
$this->db->join('contacts con','c.primary_contact = con.id','left');
$this->db->join('locations l','c.id = l.cid','left');
```

Comment: im not sure i follow how you would add that in the model page. here is what my model page looks like:
`
    $this->db->select('c.id');
    $this->db->from('company AS c');
    $this->db->join('contacts', 'contacts.id = company.primary_contact');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result_array();
`

Comment: sorry for the messed up code in my comment, apparently you cant add code to a comment, seems pretty stupid.

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure with this but you may want to try this:

```
$this->db->select('company.id','name','contacts.id','locations.id');
$this->db->from('company');
$this->db->join('contacts','company.primary_contact = contacts.id','left');
$this->db->join('locations','contacts.id = locations.id','left');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->db->select('t1.*, t2.*')
         ->join('table2 AS t2', 't1.column = t2.column', 'left');

return $this->db->get('table1 AS t1')->result();
```